# Multi Select Dropdownlist Preselection

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

I would like to fill the  `<select multiple="multiple">`
with preselected values depending on my database model.
So if there exists an record (with status >active<) for the value, the value should become selected as well as when I am deselecting a value
in the `<select multiple="multiple">`, the status of the specific record should become >inactive<.
Is there any possibility to realize that?

**Edit1:** Delete on unselection: I could just query all existing values in the database and compare it with the new submitted values, if some of them doesn't match, I probably could just make them >inactive

Comment: Got some code yet? Two things: for selecting stuff, you generate like <option val="123" selected="selected">Label</option> for those who have entries in DB. For deleting on unselection, you basically have to query your mysql db everytime for all values that haven't been set in the array of your input's selectvalue - and then delete those OR send a proper WHERE formed delete query right away...

Comment: Can't provide a code snippet so far. Just need to figure out a clean way to program that in the first place. So thanks for your guesses, I thought about that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is... assuming you are populating the select with the results from a database query, you will have something like this: (note: just code meant to learn you, it will require adjustment before you get it working for your particular app)

```
$options = mysql_query(/*your query here no idea what you're retrieving*/);
?><select multiple="multiple"><?php 
while ($option = mysql_fetch_assoc($options)) {
$selected = ($option['active']) ? 'selected="selected"':'';
echo '<option '.$selected.' value="YOUR_VALUE">YOUR_NAME</option>';
}
?></select><?php
```

Note: Replace YOUR_VALUE and YOUR_NAME with data retrieved also from the database. Not knowing what it is, couldn't tailor the code for your specific app more.