# how to set selected values to a multi select dropdown list on form load in .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using a multi select dropdown for a particular entry, which is retrieved from a table. If I am trying to edit this entry the selected dropdown is not showing.

This is my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('#Supplier').click(function () {
        var sku = $("#SKU").val();
        alert(sku);
        //var pay = null;
        //alert(suppid);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/SKUMasterSetup/supplierlist',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: sku },
            success: function (Supplierdata) {
                alert("hi");
                alert(Supplierdata);
                var x = Supplierdata.length();
                alert(x);
                //<option value="{$T.data.Value}">{$T.data.Text}</option>   
                //for (var i = 0; i < Supplierdata.length; i++) {
                //    $("#supplier").append("Selected", Supplierdata[i], "selected").attr('selected', true);

                for (var i in Supplierdata) {
                    var optionVal = Supplierdata[i];
                    $("#supplier").find("option[value=" + optionVal + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
                }

                // $('.class1').append("<option>" + "Please select" + "</option>");

            },
            //error : function (Supplier) { alert("Error !"); };
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my controller code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult supplierlist(int id)
{
   var Supplierdata = (from item in db.SupplierSKUMaps
      where item.SKU == id
      select item.SupplierMaster.SupplierName).ToList();
      return Json(Supplierdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And my dropdownlist is:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Supplier", ViewBag.Supplier as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "chosen", @id="supplier", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always use `@Value = @Html.Action(getMyFields)` and within your controller, place an action method that returns `Content result(MyData.ToList())`.

More information on creating dropdowns can be found here: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Comment: Is it possible to add retrieved values to multiselect inside the success function of jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021978/how-to-get-multiselected-dropdownlist-values-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: i can able to retrieve the data. but i dont know how to assign this data to particular multi select dropdown

Comment: Could I ask why you have to use a multi select list and not a simple ListBoxFor?

Comment: because this particular entry have multiple suppliers.

Comment: @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedFoos, new MultiSelectList(Model, "ID Property", "Display Property"), new {Multiple = "multiple"})

where Model should be IEnumerable<SomeType>

Comment: on creating a new entry,this multi select is working smoothly, i am facing this problem only in edit mode,am not getting the selected value by default.

Comment: so what you are actually ASKING is how do you retrieve the selected value(s) of the MultiSelectList?

Comment: have you your model that your using?

Comment: public class SKUViewModel
    { public List<string> Supplier { get; set; }}

Comment: did u want to see the entire model.?

Comment: here in the javascript, am getting the supplier data,but i dont know how to link this with that multi select dropdown

Comment: what is actually being edited? is it the dropdown contents? (i.e. adding a category, or renaming the category). Or is it editing the product that relates to those suppliers? Or am I not getting the point?

Comment: there is lots of suppliers we can select through the multi select dropdown,for example here, at the time of creating i selected two suppliers and save it in to the data base.So in my edit page i have to show this 2 suppliers as selected values of multi dropdown.but i can't. Did u get the point?

Comment: Why can't you edit them separately? they're two separate suppliers, so why are you trying to edit them with the same information? This was my point at the start?

Comment: actually for that particular entry,the user can add more than 1 supplier,here i added 2 suppliers in my create page.on my edit i can able to add more,but my problem is i cant able to show the selected suppliers at the time of page loading,means by default.Now u get the point?

Comment: http://rvieiraweb.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/mvc-4-dropdownlist-with-multiselect-values/ - should allow you to get the values

Comment: here am getting the selected values as a list to my view from the Viewmodel,my question is how can i assign this values as preselected.

Comment: that would need to be asked as a seperate question

Comment: is it possible to assign this list values to my multiselect dropdown? i am using chosen jquery plug in.

Comment: this was written in php, but you should get the general idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038071/multi-select-dropdownlist-preselection

Comment: i have tried that php code.but its still not coming.